# how can I override a the textfield component in extjs and use it in multiple forms accross the app?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am thinking of creating a file called MyTextField.js in views and its contents are

```
Ext.define('MyTextField',
{

override: 'Ext.field.Input',
xtype: 'mytextfield',

    updateValue: function(newValue) {
        var input = this.input;
        if (input && input.dom.value != newValue) {
            input.dom.value = newValue;
        }
    }
});
```

And then use this in my other view FormView.js

```
Ext.define('AnotherScreen', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: 'anotherscreen',
    controller: 'controllerx',
    viewModel: 'viewmodelx',
     requires: [
        'MyTextField'
    ],
    layout: 'vbox',
    items: [
             { xtype : mytextfield}
    ]

});
```

But this is not working, it returns an error

**

```
Uncaught Error: [Ext.create] Unrecognized class name / alias: 
MyTextField
```

**

Any idea is very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least three issues, one of them is missing quotes around the xtype (should be `xtype : 'mytextfield'`).

`override` tells Ext to override the old component. So `Ext.field.Input` is overridden with the updateValue function you defined. This changes every existing input field because they all derive from `Ext.field.Input` (e.g. textfield, combo etc.), but it does *not* create a new xtype by the name of "mytextfield". To create a new xtype, you extend an existing class (`extend:'Ext.field.Input'`).

At last, the idea when using requires is that the path and name of the file and the *qualified* name of the view match. If you have an application called `MyAppName`, you define in `app/view/MyTextField.js` the component `MyAppName.view.MyTextField`. When you then use `requires:['MyAppName.view.MyTextField']`, the file path should be correctly resolved and you can reference the component by xtype from there on.

Comment: Thank you @Alexander, I thought you use the override but that did not work.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me modify my code. Now it works

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be using [extend](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-modern/Ext.Class.html#cfg-extend) to create your custom class.

And in order for your class to be created using an xtype you should supply an [alias](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-modern/Ext.Class.html#cfg-alias).

Something like shown below should work:

```
Ext.define('MyTextField', {
    extend: 'Ext.field.Input',
    alias: 'widget.mytextfield',

    updateValue: function(newValue) {
        var input = this.input;
        if (input && input.dom.value != newValue) {
            input.dom.value = newValue;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work. Whenever we are defining any class, 
we should extend the parent class rather than overriding it.Please change the xxxx to the package names. when defining a class, it should always be a fully qualified name.

```
 Ext.define('xxx.xxxx.xxxx.MyTextField', {
            extend: 'Ext.field.Input',
            alias: 'widget.mytextfield',
            xtype: 'mytextfield',    
            updateValue: function(newValue) {
                var input = this.input;
                if (input && input.dom.value != newValue) {
                    input.dom.value = newValue;
                }
            }
        });
```